# Create Linear Regression Model from an array of coefficients in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have an array of coefficients already computed and I want to create a Linear Regression Model out of it in Spark 2.0.1 so that I can use it for prediction.

What is the easiest way to create a LinearRegressionModel class with an array of coefficients?

Answer (score 0):

Your linear model is just a linear equation, so for example if your coefficients are

`val coefficients=Array[Double](c0,c1,c2,...,cn)`

where the first value is the intercept coefficient (assuming you have intercept) then your linear equation is

```
y = c0 + c1*x1 + c2*x2 + ... + c_n*xn
```

So you could define

```
class LinearModel(coefficients:Array[Double]){
  def predict(newObservation:Array[Double]):Double={
  val intercept=coefficients(0)
  val weights=coefficients.drop(1)
  val multiplication=newObservation.zip(weights).map{case (x,y)=>x*y}.sum
  val prediction=intercept+multiplication
  prediction
  }
}
```

For example, if your coefficients are

`val coefficients=Array(2.0,2.1,2.2)`

then define a new linear model

```
val model = new LinearModel(coefficients)
```

So if you have a new observation

```
newObservation=Array(1.0,1.0)
```

the prediction is

```
model.predict(newObservation)
```

and the output is

```
scala> model.predict(newObservation)
res16: Double = 6.300000000000001
```

And you can adapt the previous code if you want to predict a bunch of observations instead of just one.